# The LDAP server is unavailable error when showing full name of logged user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a MVC5 project that I need to Authenticate it using user's windows login. Also I show the logged person's name at the top of the page. it is working fine in local but when I upload it to the server if show the persons Username it is showing it fine but when I show the full name I get error.

This is code that show the username and it is working both locally and on the server:

```
 <div class="right">  Logged in as <span class="username"><b>@User.Identity.Name</b></span></div>
```

this is the code that shows the user's full name that is only work locally but it is not working on the server and I get error:

```
{
         var context = new   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext(System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType.Domain);
  var principal =     System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, User.Identity.Name);
  }

<div class="right">  Logged in as <span class="username"><b> @principal.GivenName @principal.Surname</b></span></div>
```

this is the error I am getting on the server:

```
 System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapException: The LDAP server is unavailable.
```

Comment: So do you want to chat?

Comment: @jfin3204 so where you are able to chat?

Comment: I've got hangouts? jfin3204

Comment: Hi, you solved this problem?

Comment: @GauravSinghJantwal no I wasn't able to use person's first name and lastname so I

Comment: @GauravSinghJantwal No, I wasn't able to show user's First Name and Last Name and I was getting the error at the top, so I showed the username and it worked.